# How to display an Alert Dialog in a fragment

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment

I am trying to display a custom Alert Dialog in a fragment. The name of my fragment is MoviesFragFragmentActivity.java

Here is my code:

```
final AlertDialog dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MoviesFragFragmentActivity.this).create();
View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom3,null); 
dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
dialog1.setView(inflate);
TextView t1 = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.t1);

TextView t2 = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.t2);

TextView t3 = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.t3);

LinearLayout b1 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.b1);

ImageView i1 = (ImageView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.i1);

LinearLayout bg = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.bg);
t1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/en_medium.ttf"), 0);
t2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/sansation_regular.ttf"), 0);
t3.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/sansation_regular.ttf"), 0);
i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash);
i1.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#008DCD"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
t1.setText("Oh,No...");
t2.setText("This feature is not available yet, try after new update ");
t3.setText("Try again");
_rippleRoundStroke(bg, "#FAFAFA", "#000000", 40, 0, "#000000");
_CardView(b1, 10, 100, "#008DCD", true);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v){ 
        // Default item selected on bottom navigation onCreate
        bottomnavigation4.getMenu().findItem(2).setChecked(true);
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Try again later");
        dialog1.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog1.setCancelable(false);
dialog1.show();
```

On compilation, it gives me this error:

1. ERROR in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/680/app/src/main/java/com/liquidapps/movieapp/MoviesFragFragmentActivity.java (at line 601)

   final AlertDialog dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MoviesFragFragmentActivity.this).create();
   The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(MoviesFragFragmentActivity) is undefined

How does I display my alert dialog in my Fragment?

I tried using the same code in an activity (Main activity.java) and it works fine, but once I use the code in a fragment, I receive the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `MoviesFragFragmentActivity.this`